How To Make spring authorization server using opaque token to store the access token, refresh token, and authorization code in database also verify it
I want to make an authorization server on springboot with opaque token to do the validation and storing the access token, refresh token and authorization code on the database. is there a way to configure it using spring-boot-starter-oauth2-authorization-server, Since spring security works under the hood and store it to memory, how could i possibly do the validation and store to the database
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
        http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
                .oidc(Customizer.withDefaults());
        http
                .exceptionHandling(httpSecurityExceptionHandlingConfigurer -> httpSecurityExceptionHandlingConfigurer.defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(
                        new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"),
                        new MediaTypeRequestMatcher(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                ))
                .oauth2ResourceServer((resourceServer) -> resourceServer
                        .jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                // Form login handles the redirect to the login page from the
                // authorization server filter chain
                .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults());

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails userDetails = User
                .withUsername("user")
                .password("password")
                .authorities("read").build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(userDetails);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder(JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource) {
        return OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.jwtDecoder(jwkSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthorizationServerSettings authorizationServerSettings() {
        return AuthorizationServerSettings.builder()
                .build();
    }
}

i figure out how to get the client dynamically from the database, but still confused to validate and store the generated access token, refresh token, and authorization code to database. i get the Hierarchy of the code but confused to implement it on spring security oauth2 authorization server
I expect to

get the validation based on client from the database (implemented)
generate the access token, refresh token, and authorization code and store it to database
validate the generated access token, refresh token, and authorization from user and check it from the database

Thank you

Does this answer your question? How to Configure OAuth 2.0 in Spring by storing the Auth Codes in DataBase instead of ConCurrentHashMap

yes, it works thankyou. finally i could store it to the database, now i just need to figure out how the authentication works
